# material-ui alpha 1 required 'classes' prop in every component

Tags: material-ui

(version) 1.0.0-alpha.21

Every component has required property: 'classes' for css-in-js purposes.
But as an end-user I do not want to be forced to specify this prop for every component. It's just not convenient.
I get unnecessary linting warning:
[image]

How to solve this problem? Should it really be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an issue with the internal of your IDE, he isn't able to catch that the withStyles() Higher-order Component is providing the classes property.In the other words, it doesn't hamper you to use these components.